# How to implement ECS in a videogame with C++?

Tags: c++, game-design, architecture, design-patterns

What do I need to know in order to implement ECS in a video game? I'm developing a video game and so far I wasn't using any complete architecture, I was just using inheritance but I don't like it because the code became messy. 
So far, I've seen so many articles in which the subject is treated, but I don't understand how to implement it. All what I get is there is that a component is a bunch of information, an entity is a bunch of components, and each system deals with the logic of its own components. But I've got a question about it, they're a bunch of IDs, how do those IDs store data? How to retrieve data from it? I've got a problem, since I was trying to implement components, in order to do it all what I did was declare a parent abstract class in which I'd store members of that class and then I would be able to access to those members. The problem came when I was trying to declare children of that abstract class, since that parent class can't have all the members of all the another components (and I need a way to iterate all the components in a vector). 
So... I want to keep the things as simple as possible. Any advice for someone like me? How can I implement ECS in a simple platformer?
Please, Thanks in advance!

Comment: ECS will not prevent your code from being messy. Only good programming habits can do that.

Comment: But using a well defined architecture is better than not using one at all, isn't it?

Comment: There's not just one way to implement ECS, but many ways. As long as you have something in your game that could be called an "entity" something that behaves like a "component" and some kind of "system" that acts on them, you've got an ECS system. That could mean your components all derive from a base with some common methods like Update and your entities each store a list of them. Or it could mean that you store a vector of each distinct component type and an ID-to-component lookup structure to quickly find components attached to the same entity in other vectors, etc...

Comment: You seem to have read a lot of resources that talk about ECS. As DMGregory mentions, it can be _a lot_ of things. I suggest you follow _a single_ article about this, and try to implement it the way they suggest, then come back here and ask about that article with your current implementation. This way we'd have a clearer idea about your current goal and your current situation.

Comment: Just because you're not using ECS and are using inheritance doesn't mean you're not using well-defined architecture. OOP with inheritance can have very well-defined architecture. You just have to know how to use it properly.

Comment: This is the ECS that I want to implement: https://medium.com/@savas/nomad-game-engine-part-2-ecs-9132829188e5

Comment: @Almo It's not true. When inheriting all the time, you need to copy a lot of code to make everything have what it needs to have, makes you code messy. With ECS you can add exactly what you want to any of the entities without copying! It will make the code less messy!

Comment: @Joza100 _"you need to copy a lot of code"_ Why is it so?

Comment: @Alexandre Vaillancourt Let's say your entity is divided into two things such as static entity and a moving entity.  Let's say that your moving entity has HP, and your static doesn't because it doesn't need it. Then you make something that shouldn't move but actually has HP so you need to copy HP code to static entity, but then all the other static entities that don't need it will have it. That way so many entities will have useless features and you will copy code to make sure that everything is okay, but it would soon become an overkill. With ECS you add what you need to each separate entity.

Comment: @Alexandre Vaillancourt Needed to go to new comment the one was to long. 
There is a great video of a guy explaining it so watch it if you want to get a better explanation then I gave:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvEK9-CU5Og

Skip to  0:50

Comment: @Joza100 Oh ok, I think what you're describing is the first step toward what I call inheritance hell. I don't think you need to _copy_ code, but you can certainly make a nice mess out of it :)

Comment: Just because you _can_ make a mess doesn't mean you _have_ to. You're just being a fud about tech you don't like. I've written several games using inheritance and OOP techniques, and had no architecture problems. I've worked on AAA games that used inhertiance and we had no problems with architecture. I've seen it be a hideous mess, too. Like any tool, inheritance can be used well or poorly. In the end, programming is engineering, and it's more important to be pragmatic and solve the problem at hand than to adhere to some rigid idea of how things should be done.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that ECS is at its core not an object-oriented design pattern. It is more suitable for structures and functions.

> [entities are] a bunch of IDs, how do those IDs store data?

In an ECS-by-the-book architecture, entities do not store any data. Components store data. Also, neither entities nor components contain any logic. All logic is in the systems.

So you don't have an entity with a collision box. You have a vector of collision box components and some data structure which maps IDs to collision boxes (the article mentioned in the question calls these "Component Managers"). What kind of data structure is an optimization problem. But a good default solution is to use `std::map<int, CollisionBox*>`. You then have a CollisionSystem which detects and handles intersections between those collision boxes.

Sometimes it can be useful when components contain the ID of the entity they belong to so you can more easily find other components of the same entity. But not all components will need this.

---

However, this is a very C-ish style of creating an ECS system. If you feel more comfortable with a more object-oriented design, then you can also have a `class Entity` which contains pointers to all its components. You can even have a class hierarchy of entities which differ by what components they have and how they initialize them.

But the concrete instances of the components should be stored in large arrays (which you can abstract as a `std::vector` if you like) with one array for each type of component. Systems should operate on these arrays whenever possible to benefit from memory locality (iterating through an array is much faster than dereferencing a pointer).

Just don't forget about the basic principles of ECS:

- Components contain all the data
- Systems contain all the logic
- Entities say which components belong to each other

Comment: By the way, the component doesn't need to contain the ID of the entity. Simply, instead of giving the system the components it needs to operate, check if the certain entity has those components and then just send the entity to the system. That way the system will have access to all the components inside the entity. Also, entities don't just have to be IDs. They can be a class that stores components.

Comment: @Joza100 The problem with storing components inside your entities is that you lose the memory locality advantage which makes the ECS pattern so performant. But when the mechanics of your game aren't the bottleneck, then that's of course a non-issue.

Comment: I've found the most important part of ECS  to me is not the entity, or the component, but the system. Once you do your processing in a system style, you'll spot pieces of data that are only used by that system and don't need to be stored in the entity, or could be rearranged for cache performance.

Answer (score 0):

Entities don't have to be a bunch of ID's. Just create an Entity Class that will contain a list of components and that will have some methods that will help you add, remove, get, and check if the entity has certain components.

For component, just make an empty interface called component and use it for polymorphism. That way make more classes that extend Component and store data in them. Put them in the list of components that you have in your entity.

Then make systems. The way systems work is, you give your entity to your system and the system checks if that entity should be operated in that system by checking if the entity has components that the system requires. If yes, retrieve the components from the entity and make the logic in some kind of an update method that will run every time your game updates!

Also, you asked how the ID can store those components. Well, it doesn't, but in your engine class, you just store it in a HashMap. The hash map has the entity ID as a key and the List of components as the value, but as I said, better just make an Entity class that will contain the ID and the list of components! It's easier

There are many ways you can do this, this is just how I did it. There is also one tutorial series on Youtube by BennyBox who makes a 3D engine in C++.
There he uses ECS and he even programs the ECS system there. You can do the rest of the stuff by your way and just copy his ECS if you don't want to make your own or the way I explained.

Here is the link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6he35HfDmA&t=1183s